# Tkinter Button only works every once in a while?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am writing a program that requires selections to be made and data to be input with a Tkinter GUI. When trying to select checkboxes or text fields for entry, it sometimes does not click. I am currently running this on macOS and have a theory that the trackpad is the culprit, but cannot test this until later this week. For now, I wanted to paste my code and see has anyone else dealt with this? And is there something crucial I am missing. I do not believe I have any egregious loops, but more importantly this issue arises on startup of the .py file, so it should have nothing to do with loops that haven't finished, as nothing has run yet.

To clarify: my buttons work multiple times. I just have to spam click and try different areas to get them to actually select. My cursor will even indicate a type field, but clicking does not allow me to type.

Follow up question: how do I add blinking cursor to type fields?

Code:

```
# This file was generated by the Tkinter Designer by Parth Jadhav
# https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer


from pathlib import Path

# from tkinter import *
# Explicit imports to satisfy Flake8
from tkinter import *
import os
from barcode import Code128
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter 
import fitz

def img_replace(page, xref, filename=None, stream=None, pixmap=None):
    """Replace image identified by xref.

    Args:
        page: a fitz.Page object
        xref: cross reference number of image to replace
        filename, stream, pixmap: must be given as for
        page.insert_image().

    """
    if bool(filename) + bool(stream) + bool(pixmap) != 1:
        raise ValueError("Exactly one of filename/stream/pixmap must be given")
    doc = page.parent  # the owning document

    new_xref = page.insert_image(
        page.rect, filename=filename, stream=stream, pixmap=pixmap
    )
    doc.xref_copy(new_xref, xref)  # copy over new to old
    last_contents_xref = page.get_contents()[-1]

    doc.update_stream(last_contents_xref, b" ")


OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"REDACTED")


def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)


window = Tk()

window.geometry("609x450")
window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

def setPN(number):
    if number == 1:
        button1 = True

    else:
        button2 = True

def printLabel():
    serialNo = SN.get()
    CB1 = Checkbutton1.get()
    CB2 = Checkbutton2.get()

    if CB1 == 1 and serialNo != None:
        myBarCode = Code128(serialNo, writer = ImageWriter())
        myBarCode.save("tempimage")

        srcFile = "187Template.pdf"
        newFileName = serialNo+".pdf"

        doc = fitz.open(srcFile)
        page = doc[0]  # any page of doc

        img_replace(page, 6,
            filename="tempimage.png",  # or one of the following:
            stream=None,  # alternatively
            pixmap=None,  # alternatively
        )
        doc.save(newFileName,garbage=4)
        doc.close()
        os.remove("tempimage.png")

    elif CB2 == 1 and serialNo != None:
        myBarCode = Code128(serialNo, writer = ImageWriter())
        myBarCode.save("tempimage2")

        srcFile = "010Template.pdf"
        newFileName = serialNo+".pdf"

        doc = fitz.open(srcFile)
        page = doc[0]  # any page of doc

        img_replace(page, 7,
            filename="tempimage2.png",  # or one of the following:
            stream=None,  # alternatively
            pixmap=None,  # alternatively
        )
        doc.save(newFileName,garbage=4)
        doc.close()
        os.remove("tempimage2.png")

    else: 
        print("Please make sure you have entered a serial number and picked a format")
        return
    
    os.startfile(newFileName, "print")

    return


def exit():
    window.destroy()
    return

# def reset():
#     button1 = False
#     button2 = False
#     return

SN= StringVar()
Checkbutton1 = IntVar()   
Checkbutton2 = IntVar()    


canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 450,
    width = 609,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
image_1 = canvas.create_image(
    247.0,
    59.0,
    image=image_image_1
)

image_image_2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_2.png"))
image_2 = canvas.create_image(
    214.0,
    172.0,
    image=image_image_2
)

canvas.create_text(
    436.0,
    123.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="LABEL\nMAKER",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Inter ExtraBold", 40 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    21.0,
    247.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Select Model Number:",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Inter ExtraBold", 18 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    21.0,
    350.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Enter Serial Number:",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Inter ExtraBold", 18 * -1)
)

entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("entry_1.png"))
entry_bg_1 = canvas.create_image(
    429.0,
    360.5,
    image=entry_image_1
)
entry_1 = Entry(
    textvariable=SN,
    bd=0,
    bg="#FFFFFF",
    fg="#000716",
    highlightthickness=0
)
entry_1.place(
    x=281.0,
    y=349.0,
    width=296.0,
    height=21.0
)

button_1 = Checkbutton(window, text = "TLA0187",  
                      variable = Checkbutton1, 
                      onvalue = 1, 
                      offvalue = 0, 
                      height = 2, 
                      width = 10) 

button_1.place(
    x=30.0,
    y=282.0,
    width=217.0,
    height=30.0
)

button_2 = Checkbutton(window, text = "TLA0010", 
                      variable = Checkbutton2, 
                      onvalue = 1, 
                      offvalue = 0, 
                      height = 2, 
                      width = 10) 
button_2.place(
    x=281.0,
    y=281.0,
    width=217.0,
    height=30.0
)

# button_image_3 = PhotoImage(
#     file=relative_to_assets("button_3.png"))
# button_3 = Button(
#     image=button_image_3,
#     borderwidth=0,
#     highlightthickness=0,
#     command=reset,
#     relief="flat"
# )
# button_3.place(
#     x=255.0,
#     y=402.0,
#     width=90.0,
#     height=30.0
# )

button_image_4 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_4.png"))
button_4 = Button(
    image=button_image_4,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=printLabel,
    relief="flat"
)
button_4.place(
    x=21.0,
    y=402.0,
    width=90.0,
    height=25.0
)

button_image_5 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_5.png"))
button_5 = Button(
    image=button_image_5,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=exit,
    relief="flat"
)
button_5.place(
    x=138.0,
    y=402.0,
    width=90.0,
    height=30.0
)
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Disclosure: I am relatively new to python and largely self-taught. I am way more comfortable with C/C++ so this language is a little harder to grasp the natural language of. For this reason, feel free to point out any big mistakes or learning opportunities you see.

Expecting Better performance. Removed all loops.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example